# Do Hindus yell at their gods?

Tags: gods, ethics

I was watching a Norwegian documentary on religious and non-religious young people in Norway. There were two young Hindu girls who were describing what it is like to be a Hindu. I was surprised to learn that Hindus yell and scream at their gods when they are not happy with them. It is not just an issue of word choice, but they went into details about this saying things like 'the gods don't take it personally because we are like friends and family.'

I once heard something similar but exceptional in Judaism when the Jews interrogate their god, but didn't find much talk about this Hindu version online.

Do Hindus yell at their gods? Or are these young people diverting from the traditional practice?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide the link of the documentary ? BTW all over the world mankind express dissatisfaction in some way or another towards god  while going through difficult times like blaming him not helping them or about not listening to prayers etc.It is general tendency of us all.Hindus do not yell at god at such and it's unheard of.

Comment: Hindus don't have such customs of yelling at deities.

Comment: Though this is not an answer, most Hindus consider God as someone intimate; so in an intimate relationship, emotions fly everywhere.

Comment: Well this is interesting. I have never encountered this before.

Comment: If you're devoted, not only can you yell, you can also order. like a devoted wife yells at her husband for coming home late from office. @Rickross

Comment: So we have to go to individual homes to find out if someone is yelling at deities or not? I have said that there are no such customs and that is indeed true. @ram

Comment: @Rickross - you can find various Bhakta Charitra (e.g. Bhadrachala Rama Das) who 'scold' Bhagavan in Kirtanas. Lakshmana 'scolds' Rama for being too submissive to Varuna. There is no need for a formal scripture or festival or Smriti injunction for somethng to be a custom. Devotees have always had the right to interact with Bhagavan as they like. This is one of the most true customs of Hinduism.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Check this link around timestamp 4:19 https://tv.nrk.no/serie/religion/sesong/2/episode/2/avspiller

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not aware of any survey on this issue. However, Hindu relationship with the deities is not governed by fear. So it might be that some Hindus yell at the deities.

> Yoga Vasistha II.18 says:
>
> yuktiyuktamupādeyaṃ vacanaṃ bālakādapi | anyattṛṇamiva tyājyamapyuktaṃ
> padmajanmanā || 3 ||
>
> The remark of a child is to be accepted, if it is in accordance with
> reason; but the remark of even Brahma Himself, the creator of the
> world is to be rejected like a piece of straw if it does not accord
> with reason.

**REF: Vasistha's Yoga translated by Swami Venkatesananda, p 35.**

> The central idea of ours is that **there is no thought of fear**. It is
> always, love God. **There is no worship through fear**, but always through
> love, from beginning to end.

**The Complete Works of Swami Vivekananda, Volume V, Questions and Answers, A Discussion**

I do not know the number of Hindus who yells at the deities or if any Hindu yells at all but the girls are right on the money that the deities worshipped in the households become family members of the household.

Comment: One yells when he is angry and not when he is afraid. I am not sure how are your quotes answering the question.

Comment: On would not yell if one is afraid. So my quotes are appropriate.

Comment: "One would not yell if one is afraid" yes but where is the proof that "one who is not afraid will yell"? Is your answer proving that?